# Questions about Mean-field variational inference

Tags: normal-distribution, mean, inference, kullback-leibler, variational-bayes

I am very new to this variational  inference concept. I couldn't find any clear sources. I have two questions related to each other.

Let's consider a very simple probabilistic model with a 2-D latent variable z ∈ $R^2$ and an observed variable
$x ∈ R$.
The prior over the latent variable is

$p(z) = N (z | 0, I) = N (z_1 | 0, 1) · N (z_2 | 0, 1),$

and the likelihood is

$p(x | z) = N (x | θ^Tz, 1),$

where $θ ∈ R^2$ is a known and fixed parameter.

I want to write down the true posterior distribution $p(z | x)$ up to the normalizing constant. Can the posterior be factorized over $z_1$ and $z_2$ ? In other words how can I express in terms of  $p(z_1 | x)p(z_2 | x)$

Another question of mine is let's suppose we approximate the true posterior using a mean-field variational distribution in other words:

$q(z) = q_1(z_1)q_2(z_2) = N (z_1 | m_1, s_2) · N (z_2 | m_2, s_2)$

How can I derive the optimal updates for $q_1$ and $q_2$? Is $q(z)$ able to match the true posterior?

Thanks for all the help!